# limits of sequences using epsilon

Tags: limits

I was trying to do this question proving the limit of $An=(3n^2+2n+1)/(n^2+1)$ using L'Hopitals rule we can see the limit is 3. I wrote $|An-3|=(2n-2)/(n^2+1)$ so $|An-3|<2/n $
:n>1   if (2/n) (2/epsilon)

for $ n>N $

$n>N>\frac{2}{\epsilon }->  (2/n)<\epsilon 
$

This gives$  |An-3|<(2/n)<\epsilon$ which shows $(An)$ is convergent to $3 
$.

Is the working out on this correct? And if so how could I structure it better?

Comment: This is very difficult to read.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you cannot use l'Hôpital's rule, because to do that you'd have to differentiate a sequence, which makes no sense. Rigorously, what you can do is extend the sequence to the function $f(x) = \frac{3x^2+2x+1}{x^2+1}$, use l'Hôpital's rule on the function $f$ and prove that if $f$ is convergent so is $f|_{\mathbb{N}}=(A_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, which is easy. The proof is correct, though, but quite messy.

---

For every $\epsilon > 0$, by the Archemedean property there exists a $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n_0 > \frac2\epsilon$. Since, for every $n \in \mathbb{Ǹ}$, we have $|A_n-3|<\frac2n$, taking $n > n_0$ we have $$|A_n-3| < \frac2n < \epsilon.$$ Completing the proof.